# How to access tabular form data in oracle apex 18.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, tabular-form, oracle-apex-18.2

How to access tabular form data in oracle apex.I need to insert data based on access data in tabular form. please any one help me to solve my problem

Comment: Can you confirm that you mean tabular form, not interactive grid?

Comment: If you have an application developed in APEX 4.x with tabular forms, it should work as before. If you have APEX 18.2 and want to create a new tabular form - it is impossible, use Interactive Grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {

    function update(model) {
        var salKey = model.getFieldKey("SAL"), 
            total = 0;

        model.forEach(function(record, index, id) {
            var sal = parseInt(record[salKey], 10),  
                meta = model.getRecordMetadata(id);

            if (!isNaN(sal) && !meta.deleted && !meta.agg) {
                total += sal;
            }
        });
        $s("P1_TOTAL_AMOUNT", total);
    }

    $(function() {

        $("#emp").on("interactivegridviewmodelcreate", function(event, ui) {
            var sid,
                model = ui.model;

            if ( ui.viewId === "grid" ) {
                sid = model.subscribe( {
                    onChange: function(type, change) {
                        if ( type === "set" ) {

                            if (change.field === "SAL" ) {
                                update( model );
                            }
                        } else if (type !== "move" && type !== "metaChange") {

                            update( model );
                        }
                    },
                    progressView: $("#P1_TOTAL_AMOUNT") 
                } );

                update( model ); 

                model.fetchAll(function() {});
            }
        });
    });
})(apex.jQuery);
```

Comment: it will capture your all data of salry column.

Comment: Please anyone gives another example for this question